# How to know if a slug belongs to a page in Nextjs 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, ecmascript-6, next.js13

I am trying to make a dynamic breadcrumb component with custom values in Nextjs 13.

Let's say I have the route: `/dashboard/[tenant]/[invoice]/editor/abcd`.

Currently, I do an API call and populate `[tenant]` and `[invoice]` with custom names in my `Breadcrumb component`; E.g the name of the tenant and document instead of the id's.

Now I would like to render a link for `[invoice]` and 'editor' and 'abcd' which are all pages, except for `[tenant]`.

**How can I distinct between a slug that is a page and a slug that isn't a page?**

I know for example that 'abcd' is a page because it is the end of the url. But I would not know that for 'editor'.

I tried using the `useParams` hook but that only returns the values in the URL of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a page as `/dashboard/invoice/[invoice]/` and populate the page with the invoice details.

Change your editor call to `/dashboard/editor/[tenant]/[invoice]`

Alternatively, if you insist on your paths, you can name your tenants and invoice with specific string e.g. tenant-1234, invoice-1234, then in /dashboard/[pid], you can check your pid for the tenant or invoice string and generate the associated component. Though, that's more work than necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

I updated my post because I would also like to know if a non-dynamic slug is a page. In that case I can not use the 'page-1234' technique you advised as I would have in my url 'editor-1234' which is a bit strange.

Comment: what u mean a non dynamic slug is a page? Yes if you put invoice.tsx inside the slug folder, then invoice.tsx will take priority over the slug

Comment: Wasn’t too sure if thats correct naming. But I just mean the part of an url that doesn’t changes. So dashboard/[tenant]/editor/[invoice] Both editor and [invoice] are a folder with a page.tsx. How will i know that ‘dashboard/[tenant]/editor’ is a page in my breadcrumb component

Comment: breadcrumb component should read the url to determine where the user is at.

Answer (score -1):

In Next.js 13, you can use the `useRouter` hook to get information about the current route, including the path and query parameters. To determine if a part of the slug corresponds to a page, you can compare it against your known routes. Here's how you can do it:

1. Import the `useRouter` hook from `next/router`:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
```

2. Define an array of known routes in your component or a separate configuration file. This array should contain the parts of the slug that correspond to pages:

```
const knownRoutes = ['editor', 'abcd'];
```

3. Use the `useRouter` hook to get information about the current route, and then extract the slug from it. You can split the slug into its parts using the `/` delimiter:

```
const { asPath } = useRouter();
const slugParts = asPath.split('/').filter(Boolean); // filter out empty strings
```

4. Check if each part of the slug is a known route or not. If it's a known route, you can render a link; otherwise, you can just display the text:

```
return (
  <div>
    {slugParts.map((part, index) => {
      if (knownRoutes.includes(part)) {
        // Render a link for known routes
        return (
          <Link key={index} href={asPath.split(part)[0] + part}>
            <a>{part}</a>
          </Link>
        );
      } else {
        // Display text for other parts of the slug
        return <span key={index}>{part}</span>;
      }
    })}
  </div>
);
```

In the code above, we split the slug into its parts, iterate through them, and check if each part is in the `knownRoutes` array. If it is, we render a link for that part; otherwise, we display it as text. This way, you can distinguish between slugs that correspond to pages and those that don't.

Comment: Hey Ronak thanks for your reply! I figured I would have to do something like this. Would have rather had an automatic way to get the know routes (just like the new typed routes feature). But guess I will have to make do with that for now!